# Pointer variable pointing to a one dimensional array or two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I have the following code for a one dimensional array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int b[4] = {11, 12, 13, 14};
    int (*p)[4];

    p = b;
    printf("%d \n", *(p + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Even though I consider "b (the array name)" as a pointer pointing to a one dimensional array, I got a compiling error as

```
'=': cannot convert from 'int [4]' to 'int (*)[4]'
```

However, if I change b array into a two dimensional array "a (the array name)", everything works fine. Does this mean that, in the usage of "int (*p)[4];", "*p" has to represent a[] as in the following:

```
static int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12} };
int (*p)[4];
p = a;
```

As a result, "int (*p)[4]" only provides the flexibility on the number of rows of a two dimensional array.

Any insights on this problem?

Comment: `p = b;` -> `p = &b;` since `p` is a pointer to an array. Just like `int a; int *p = &a;`. With `p = a` in the second example with the 2D array, `p` points to the first 1D array in `a`.

Comment: I think b itself is an address because b is a one dimensional array name. Therefore, p = b instead of p = &b. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Cindy No, `b` is an *array*. As mentioned in my answer, arrays can *decay* to pointers (to their first element), but they aren't pointers (addresses) themselves.

Comment: @Cindy and `b` can decay to an `int *` in your example but it is still not the same type as `int (*)[4]`. `&b` is of the type `int (*)[4]` so it works. `b` (decayed into a pointer) and `&b` have the same address but are still different types.

Comment: `(*p)[4] .. only provides flexibility in the number of rows` -- yes.  C arrays are row-major (matching storage layout).  To calculate the address of a row, the compilers needs the number of columns;  if you want column flexibility, you need to drop the [4], and calculate the row yourself; eg: `int *p = b;  p[2*4+1] = 3;` would assign row=2,col=1 the value 3.   Or if you wanted to think of `b` as a 3-wide array: `p[2*3+1] = 3;` would assign row=2,col=1 the value 3.  It might help to put the cumbersome type into a definition, both to clarify things, but also to keep it from looking like c++:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an object of some type `T` like

```
T a;
```

then declaration of a pointer to the object will look like

```
T *p = &a;
```

Your array `b` has the type `int[4]`. So a pointer to the array will look like

```
int ( *p )[4] = &b;
```

To output the second element of the array using the pointer you should write

```
printf("%d \n", *( *p + 1 ) );
```

Thus your compiler issued the error message

> cannot convert from 'int [4]' to 'int (*)[4]

because instead of writing at least

```
int ( *p )[4] = &b;
```

you wrote

```
int ( *p )[4] = b;
```

On the other hand, an array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. For example in this declaration

```
int *p = b;
```

the array `b` used as an initializer is converted to pointer to its firs element. The above declaration is equivalent to

```
int *p = &b[0];
```

or that is the same

```
int *p = b + 0;
```

Using this pointer you can call the function `printf` like

```
printf("%d \n", *(p + 1));
```

If you have a two-dimensional array as

```
int a[3][4];
```

then used in expressions it is converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `int[4]`. So you may write

```
int ( *p )[4] = a;
```

If you want to declare a pointer to the whole array as a single object you can write

```
int ( *p )[3][4] = &a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first elements, depending on context. That is, when such a decay happen then plain `b` is the same as `&b[0]`, which have the type `int *`. Since the types of `p` and `b` (or `&b[0]`) are different you get an error.

As for `a` it's the same thing here, it decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. ***But*** since `a[0]` is an array of `4` elements, then `&a[0]` is a pointer to an array of four elements, or `int (*)[4]`. Which is also the type of `p` in the second example.

Comment: So, plain b has the type of int*. What is the type of p if p and b have different types?

Comment: @Cindy No plain `b` really have the type `int[4]`, but it can *decay* to `int *`. And the type of `p` is clearly declared as `int (*)[4]` which is very different from `int *`.

Comment: Again, what is the type of p? Is it int* or a[] equivalently?

Comment: @Cindy `p` is declared as `int (*p)[4];` which means it has the type `int (*)[4]`.

Comment: So, the compiler error actually says I can't make a equal sign between p (type int*) and the original type of b (type int[4]) even though b's type can decay to int*?

Comment: @Cindy Again, the type of `p` is **`int (*)[4]`**, not `int *` as you continue to say.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's contributions here. It solves my problem.

Comment: Re “Arrays naturally decay”: This is not mentioned in any scientific study of the natural world. That is because the conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element is a deliberate and programmed behavior, not “natural.”

Answer (score 0):

> a pointer pointing to a one dimensional array,

No, it points directly to the first element. Likewise:

```
int *p = b;
```

is enough.

The number `4` is not really part of any type here;

```
 static int b[] = {11, 12, 13, 14};
```

It can be left out in the declaration. (Because it is the *first* dimension unless you make it 2D)

---

This (from AA)

```
int (*p)[4] = &b;
...
printf("%d \n", *( *p + 1 ) );
```

is just a obfuscated and overtyped version of:

```
int (*p)[] = &b;
...
printf("%d \n", (*p)[1] );
```

This replaces `b` with `(*p)`, normally not what you want.

Comment: _The number 4 is not really part of any type here;_ Pretty sure it is. An `int (*)[4]` can't point to an `int` array of length 5.

Comment: With "here" I mean the 1D case. gcc says `int *`, OP has `int [4]` in the message. But `int (*)[4]` is 2D - there `4` is part of the type.

Comment: An array does not point to its first element. It is **converted** to a pointer to its first element when it is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof`, as the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array. Understanding this separate step in handling of an array is important to understanding C semantics. Arrays should not be thought of as pointers.